# Announcing an upcoming election

Tags: discussion

**Summary**: Islam Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://islam.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **June 28**, as your "graduation" election (as a result of [having lost your beta label](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3429/12284) a while back).

The timeline:

- On June 21, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on June 28, users can [nominate themselves](https://islam.stackexchange.com/election/1). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a second Meta post, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- On July 5, if there are four or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for one more week. If at the end of this extension period there are still not four or more candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods) and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on July 13 (or on the 20th, if we need to extend the nomination period and only get 4 or more candidates then).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, this is exciting! My first ever election on the Stack Exchange. I hope to be nominated for such a role; definitely will be nominating myself!

Comment: You can nominate yourself by now.

Comment: @Medi1Saif thank you, but unfortunately, I'm 17, not 18.

Comment: Oh OK then next time.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Insha'Allah

Answer (score 1):

Due to the actual state of the "reaction" on this important announcement, which anybody who joined the site when it was launched or in its early days or years of existence was eagerly waiting for.
I must ask:

- what if participation is very low or what if about nobody is running or applying for candidacy?
- Or in other words what if no one except possibly the current moderators is nominated?

It would have a bad taste to be voted because almost no one is actively involved or even regards the election as such big opportunity for the maturity of the site. This is not -at least- my understanding of democracy.

I would like to see significantly more attention for this announcement and for the upcoming election I hope for lively participation.

Comment: I think the post covers what happens if the election doesn't have enough candidates, no? If only the current mods nominate the election will be cancelled, and nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to encourage an active Shia to be a candidate because I think that there is less information and activity from Shia in the last time.

(Note : I am a Sunni)

Comment: A moderators own personal beliefs is not the metric you should use when evaluating their suitability for the role, and the information they provide themselves in answers is orthogonal to being a moderator. In fact most moderators end up contributing *less* content as moderators than they did as users. It sounds you you are looking for active contributors, not a moderator. Don't mix up the two roles or you'll get the wrong people for the job.

Comment: @Caleb You are quite right there.  It might be a sign, not more.

Answer (score 1):

Beside a shi'a users I would encourage a female user to participate in the starting nomination and election.

One question to what extent stackexchange supports the idea of nominating a user by another user - instead of self-nomination? In other words is suggesting a user for moderation allowed?

Comment: The UI only allows for self-nominations, so that's not an option here. We've done that in the past for pro-tem elections, but we require all nominations to be self-nominations nowadays.